# I need to create a zip file using python. But unfortunately my code is not working.Is there any error on my part?

Tags: zip

**So i wish to create a zip file named new.zip using python which also contains a text file called sample.txt. But after running the necessary code on my python editor i get the error as :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/PYTHON_CODE/creatingZipFile.py", line 5, in 
newZip.write('sample.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1713, in write
zinfo = ZipInfo.from_file(filename, arcname)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 506, in from_file
st = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'sample.txt'

My python code is as below :

```
import os, zipfile

os.chdir("F:\\")
newZip = zipfile.ZipFile('new.zip', 'a')
newZip.write('sample.txt', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
newZip.close()
```

PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME REGARDING THIS ISSUE.**

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'sample.txt'

will occur if the file is not present in the specified path, can you check if sample.txt is actually present in the path F:\sample.txt